# Can Solana be EVM compatible where it would be able to use metamask?

Tags: wallet, ethereum, neon-evm

Solana's system is similar to Ethereum as they both use account based ledger system and not UTXO's like bitcoin. Is there a way to make Solana EVM compatible so it would work on metamask?

Currently metamask just connects to a RPC node to query the balance of an ethereum address, but why can't a Solana node with some type of bridge that just outputs the same data format for interoperability with metamask? What are some technical limitations that prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

The account model of Solana is very different than Ethereum.

There is a project on Solana called Neon. They are bringing the EVM to Solana, where you could use Metamask.

You can learn more here: https://neon-labs.org

They are still in devnet.